# centOS php 5.3 warnings are not logged to the error log

Tags: php, apache, centos

I am running PHP 5.3 on CentOS. There are no PHP warning being written to the error log. My configuration is as follows

```
php.ini

log_errors = On

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

My virtual host conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:9101>
    DocumentRoot /home/parvhraban/domains/src/www_root
    php_value include_path ".:/home/parvhraban/phplibs:/home/parvhraban/domains/src/local_libs"
    ErrorLog /home/parvhraban/log/error9101.log
    CustomLog /home/parvhraban/log/access9101.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems the settings are correct but only fatal errors are being logged. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that those settings are being seen by the code?

Comment: conf file definitely works as I can see the error log and access the vhost itself. phpinfo says Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini which is the file I quoted

Comment: Are you sure there is no call to error_reporting in your code that's overwriting what errors to log?

Answer (score 0):

After changing your php.ini restart the server